# jquery-ui droppable: prevent parent from accepting children

Tags: jquery-ui, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-droppable

I'm making a document list, and I need to stop a draggable element being accepted by its parent. The option is set like:

```
$( ".onedoc" ).droppable({
accept: ".onedoc"
});
```

but I want the droppable not to accept its immediate children. The problem is since it's a nested list, the parents and children have the same classes, so I need to do something like

```
accept: $(".onedoc").not($(this).children())
```

but of course this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because `accept:` is looking for a selector and your are providing it with a jQuery object?

How about you provide it with a function?

```
$(".onedoc").droppable({
    accept: function (elem) {
        // check elem here for being a child and return false
        return !$(this).has(elem).length;
    }
});
```

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'has'.  Was I supposed to change something? This is a bit beyond me, I don't know how a function returning true/false can  help in this case. I need to accept elements of .onedoc except those that are the immediate children of the element being a droppable in this case (so users can't drop an element on or see hoverClass of its parent).